# MassTransit SignalR Bindings

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, signalr, masstransit

I'm having some issues setting up my MassTransit SignalR solution. I have posted a question before regarding bindings which Chris answered and helped me out but after updating the packages (i was still using 6.x.x which had other issues like restarting RabbitMQ service would origin in an error when sending messages) my bindings don't seem to work properly anymore.

This was the first question i asked: [Exchange binding not working in MassTransit with RabbitMQ and SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571660/exchange-binding-not-working-in-masstransit-with-rabbitmq-and-signalr)

Now i have updated to the 7.1.7 and also updated the methods that were deprecated. This is how my Startup looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Utilities utilities = new Utilities(Configuration);

        RabbitMQIdentity rabbitMQIdentity = utilities.GetRabbitMQIdentity();
        var username = rabbitMQIdentity.UserName;
        var password = rabbitMQIdentity.Password;
        var hostName = rabbitMQIdentity.HostName;
        var portNumber = rabbitMQIdentity.Port;

        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSignalR(e => {
            e.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
        });

        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddSignalRHub<NotificationHub>();

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host($"amqp://{username}:{password}@{hostName}:{portNumber}");

                cfg.AutoDelete = true;
                cfg.Durable = false;
                cfg.QueueExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

        services.AddSingleton<IHostEnvironment>(hostEnvironment);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<LogConfigurationUtility, WebLogConfigurationUtility>();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetIsOriginAllowed((x) => Configuration["CorsWhiteList"].Split(';').Any(x.Contains))
                       .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseMiddleware<RequestMiddleware>();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationhub");
        });
    }
```

And here is my publish:

```
logger.LogInformation($"MassTransit publishing group message. GroupName:{paymentCallback.OrderId} ; Message:{paymentCallback.Event}");

IReadOnlyList <IHubProtocol> protocols = new IHubProtocol[] { new JsonHubProtocol() };

publishEndpoint.Publish<Group<NotificationHub>>(
                new GroupHub<NotificationHub>()
                {
                    GroupName = paymentCallback.OrderId,
                    Messages = protocols.ToProtocolDictionary("Notify", new object[] { paymentCallback.Event })
                },
                context => context.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
            );
```

And the client:

```
useEffect(() => {
$(function() {
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(hubUrl)
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
        .build();
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    connection.on("Notify", (status) => {
        console.log("entrouuuuuu");
        setNotification(status);
    });
    // Start the connection.
    async function start() {
        try {
            await connection.start();
            connection.invoke("InitializeClient", orderId);
            console.log("SignalR Connected.");
        } catch (err) {
            setTimeout(start, 5000);
        }
    }

    start();
});
```

So now, in RabbitMQ management tools i can see the exchange being created but again it has no bindings and it has also no queues. Does the same issue still persist Chris? Or am i doing something wrong?

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As [discussed on Discord](https://discord.com/invite/rNpQgYn), the [SignalR Sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-SignalR) is a working baseline to review.

Comment: I found out why the bindings were not working. As i said i performed a rabbitMQ restart with a lower MT version (6..) and then found out there was a solved issue regarding that restart since endpoints not being created by MT.

So i updated the packages and the DI code and it still didn't work. I had to re install rabbitMQ to get masstransit to create my endpoints again, it seems that updating the packages and re-trying the process flow from the beggining was not enough which cased my issue.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the help and the time you spent helping me out, i would suggest though maybe adding more information in how SignalR backplane works/communicates with masstransit and the hubs. There isn't many implementations of this and knowing what's happening in the background in more detail could prevent some basic mistakes. Sorry for double comment, too many characters